# Proof about $f$ with slant asymptotes

Tags: functions, derivatives, asymptotics

Let $f$ be a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$. We say $f$ is a candy cane at $\infty$ if there exists A, B $\in \mathbb{R}$ with A $\neq$ 0 such that
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{Ax + B} = 1$$
Is each of the following statements true or false? If true, prove it. If false, show it with a counterexample.
(a) IF $f$ has a slant asymptote at $\infty$ THEN $f$ is a candy cane at $\infty$.
(b) IF $f$ is a candy cane at $\infty$ THEN $f$ has a slant asymptote at $\infty$.

(a) This is what I have soo far:
If f has a slant asymptote at $\infty$, then
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} [f(x) - (mx + c)] = 0 $$
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} mx + c $$
Substituting $\lim_{x \to \infty} mx+ c$ for $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ we get
$$ \frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} mx + c}{\lim_{x \to \infty} Ax + B} = 1$$
Taking x as the dominant term we get
$$\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} m + \frac{c}{x}}{\lim_{x \to \infty} A + \frac{B}{x}} = 1$$
Since $\frac{c}{x}$ and $\frac{B}{x}$ go to zero since $c$ and $B$ are constants divided by a large number, we can conclude that
$$\frac{m}{A} = 1$$
This is because the limit of a constant is a constant. Thus
$$m = A$$
Then it must be true that f is a candy cane.

(b) For b, I'm kind of unsure
If f is a candy cane at $\infty$, then
$$\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)}{\lim_{x \to \infty} Ax + B} = 1$$
I want to say that since the limit value is 1, $f(x)$ must be a linear function as well. I can take three cases:
Case 1: when degree of $f(x)$ is $>$ 1.
Case 2: when degree of $f(x)$ is $<$ 1.
Case 3: when degree of $f(x)$ is  equal to 1.
And I can then conclude that it must the case that $f(x) is a linear function and must have a slant asymptote.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What is the degree of $f$ if it is not a polynomial function?

Comment: @Bernard honestly didn't think about that. Would it be alright if i specify that $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: It also can be a rational function. Other than that, your definition means tha $f(x) is asymptotically equivalent to some $Ax+B$. But the latter is equivalent to its leading term $Ax$, so I don't see what's the usefulness of the constant term.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+\ln (x)}{x} =1$$
This shows that $x+\ln(x)$ is a candy cane at $\infty$.
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {x+\ln (x)-mx-c}=\infty$$
if $m \leqslant 1$.
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {x+\ln (x)-mx-c}=-\infty$$
if $m>1$. Thus, $x+\ln(x)$ has no slant asymptote. This proves that claim (b) is false.

To show that (a) is true, if we have:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)-mx-c=0 \implies \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)-mx-c}{mx+c}=0$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{mx+c}-1=0 \implies \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{mx+c}=1$$
Now, take $A=m$ and $B=c$. Note that you couldn't directly transposed $mx+c$ to the other side and then divide since both limits are infinite in value. Thus, you must divide inside the limit itself first.

This shows that claim (a) is true.

Comment: By the way, claim (a) is true. You mustn't directly transpose the way you did it in your proof since the limits may be infinite. You must divide first by $mx+c$. That will directly give you the value as $1$.

Comment: So my claim for (a) is correct? Also any recommendations on making that proof better? (im very new to proofs)

Comment: @UnKnoWnZ I have written the proof above with clarification

Answer (score 0):

For (a), you say that
$$ \frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} mx + c}{\lim_{x \to \infty} Ax + B} \stackrel?= 1.\tag1$$

This is not OK. You have written a "fraction" in which the denominator goes to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$. 
Likewise (if $m\neq 0$) the numerator also goes to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$.
This gives you an indeterminate form.

Your next formula *is* OK,
$$\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} m + \frac{c}{x}}{\lim_{x \to \infty} A + \frac{B}{x}}
 = 1,\tag2$$
because the two limits are both finite and the denominator is not zero.
So the thing to do (in cases where you need to get to a formula such as $(2)$) is to go from
$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{mx + c}{Ax + B} = 1$
to Equation $(2)$ without passing through Equation $(1).$
You can do this by dividing numerator and denominator by $x$ *before* you try to take the limit of each one separately.
(Aside from the fact that  Equation $(1)$ is not OK, dividing each of two limits by the limit variable is also questionable.)

However, in this case all of this is unnecessary. All you need to do is to *"guess"* that $A=m$ and $B=c$ and then show that 
$ \lim_{x \to \infty} [f(x) - (mx + c)] = 0 $
implies
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{mx + c} = 1 .$$

For (b), note that the only polynomials that are candy canes are the first-degree polynomials $ax + b$ where $a \neq 0.$
So for the question to be interesting at all, we have to deal with functions that are not polynomials, for example, $x + \sin x.$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Still getting a hold on proofs especially involving limits.